# C# simple error: Storing characters in a string array

Tags: c#

I want to store every single character of a string value in every single place of a string array.

I wrote this code but Visual Studio says that "Cannot implicitly convert type String to String []".

Can you please tell me how to fix this?

```
string [] array = Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: You obviously come from a C-world - try thinking of strings as something unique on their own, not as arrays of chars.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Console.ReadLine` does not return an array but a `string`:

```
string line = Console.ReadLine();
```

In your code, the variable `array` is declared as a string array, so the result of `Console.ReadLine` cannot be assigned to it.

Comment: Okay. Is my string variable automatically an array?

Comment: A string can be seen as an indexed list of chars, and you can get an actual char[] with the ToCharArray method. The question is: what for?

Answer (score 1):

You can get an array of characters (char[]) with the ToCharArray() method of String. You can then use LINQ or something to convert each individual char to a string.

Very weird request though.

Answer (score 0):

Console.ReadLine() returns a string. Then if you really need a char array, you can use [string.ToCharArray()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.tochararray.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

The answer depends on your definition of "character". If you are talking about code points (i.e., `char`s) then there are several answers given. If you are talking about linguistic characters, then here is a way to do it:

```
        string[] array = GetAllCharacters(Console.ReadLine()).ToArray();
```

Using this method:

```
using System.Globalization;
...
    private static IEnumerable<string> GetAllCharacters(string text)
    {
        TextElementEnumerator elementEnumerator = StringInfo.GetTextElementEnumerator(text);
        while (elementEnumerator.MoveNext())
            yield return (string)elementEnumerator.Current;
    }
```